# Using JavaScript to Modify a Page on the Fly based on <select> contents

Tags: php, javascript

So, I've got a form and within that form is a `<select>`. Based on what that select is(what `<option>` is selected), I want the contents of the form to change on the fly(i.e. before the user clicks anything else).

For example, if the user selects the `Photo Upload` option, a file upload box will appear, and if they select `Text Entry`, a text box will appear in place of that file upload box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function swapDiv( index ) {
    var html = '';
    switch( index ) {
       ... // assign html var based on index;
    }
    div.innerHTML = html; // assign div html to html var
}
select.onchange = function() {
    swapDiv( this.selectedIndex );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being totally clueless on javascript, but I can't get this working. What would the entire HTML document look like? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event to trigger the file upload (or whatever).

Comment: Yes, I know that I should be using the `onchange` event, I just don't know how to make the JS function do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

this using jquery:

```
$(function ()
{
    var shown = $($('#my-select').val());

    $('#my-select').change(function ()
    {
        shown.hide();
        shown = this.form.find($(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

expects such html:

```
<style>
textarea, input { display: none; }
</style>
<form id="my-form">
  <textarea id="text-entry"></textarea>
  <input type="file" id="file-upload">
  <select id="my-select">
    <option value="#text-entry">Text Entry</option>
    <option value="#file-upload">File Upload</option>
  </select>
</form>
```